# How to transfer erc20 coin multiple to single wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, tokens, wallets

I have many eth adress with ERC20 tokens. How can i transfer to single wallet all of them?

Comment: Duplicate. Have a look at for example: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40885/how-to-send-multiple-transactions-from-wallet-at-once/40888#40888 (and its duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a transaction for each of the addresses where you have tokens, that transfers them to the single target address. There is no way to collapse it into a single transaction with the standard ERC20 interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this: https://etherchain.tools/airdropper

It can send ether/erc20 token to multiple address

Comment: That is the opposite of what has been asked.